# How do I write a custom filename completer for specific directories in zsh?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I've found that file names with dates before the title are difficult to tab-completion. I'd like to write custom completion functions for these directories. How do I specify that the completer should be used instead of the default?

Comment: What exactly is difficult about them to tab-complete? And how would you want the tab completion to work for these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to *specify* it, but you can patch the [`_path_files` completion function](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Completion/Unix/Type/_path_files) to achieve this:

```bsh
# Load the `functions` table.
zmodload -Fa zsh/parameter p:functions

# Load the definition of _path_files.
autoload +X -Uz _path_files

# Make a copy of it.
functions[_original_path_files]=$functions[_path_files]

# Replace the original.
_path_files() {
  # `$words[CURRENT]` is the current word under completion.
  # `:a` turns it into an absolute path.
  if [[ $words[CURRENT]:a == <pattern that matches the dirs in question>/* ]]; then
    <your special completion function> "$@"
  else
    _original_path_files "$@"
  fi
}
```

Documentation:

- [`zsh/parameter`'s `functions` table](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-functions-2)
- [Builtin command `autoload`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-autoload)
- [Parameter expansion modifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers)